# Python exercise, execution time

Tags: python

this was for a leetcode problem and i was wondering my solution is slower than the proposed one, could you give me some insights perhaps of time complexity and why at the end my code is slower?

my code:

```
class Solution:
    def numUniqueEmails(self, emails: 'List[str]') -> 'int':
        forward_emails = set()
        for email in emails:
            fw_email = []

            idx = 0
            while email[idx] != '@' and email[idx] != '+':
                if email[idx] != '.':
                    fw_email.append(email[idx])
                idx += 1

            if email[idx] == '+':
                idx += 1
                while email[idx] != '@':
                    idx += 1

            while idx < len(email):
                fw_email.append(email[idx])
                idx += 1

            forward_emails.add(''.join(fw_email))

        return len(forward_emails)
```

proposed solution:

```
class Solution(object):
    def numUniqueEmails(self, emails):
        seen = set()
        for email in emails:
            local, domain = email.split('@')
            if '+' in local:
                local = local[:local.index('+')]
            seen.add(local.replace('.','') + '@' + domain)
        return len(seen)
```

I was expecting my solution to be faster given that I was iterating through the strings only once and then making the join, while on the other hand, the proposed solution run methods such as split, index, slicing that I thought would cost more.

if you need more context of the problem, let me know.

Comment: Methods like `split`, `index` are in fact much faster than manual iteration. This is because they are implemented in C, in which simple loops can be up to 100x faster than Python.

Comment: The methods will also work directly with strings, rather than copying their contents into a list one character at a time.

Comment: You can do profiling in Python and find where the time is spent...

Comment: @user200783 thanks for the insight, my understanding was that `replace` asymptotically could be higher than O(n), which I'm not sure if it's a right statement, thus I went with my approach